# PHP Spark Serve looking some port and exited

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

I just run `php spark serve`, and this happen

```
CodeIgniter v4.3.2 Command Line Tool - Server Time: 2023-03-14 05:43:21 UTC+00:00

CodeIgniter development server started on http://localhost:8080
Press Control-C to stop.
CodeIgniter development server started on http://localhost:8081
Press Control-C to stop.
CodeIgniter development server started on http://localhost:8082
Press Control-C to stop.
CodeIgniter development server started on http://localhost:8083
Press Control-C to stop.
CodeIgniter development server started on http://localhost:8084
Press Control-C to stop.
CodeIgniter development server started on http://localhost:8085
Press Control-C to stop.
CodeIgniter development server started on http://localhost:8086
Press Control-C to stop.
CodeIgniter development server started on http://localhost:8087
Press Control-C to stop.
CodeIgniter development server started on http://localhost:8088
Press Control-C to stop.
CodeIgniter development server started on http://localhost:8089
Press Control-C to stop.
CodeIgniter development server started on http://localhost:8090
Press Control-C to stop.
```

I have changed the port with `php spark serve --port 8000`. The result is same. still looking some port.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can read this thread: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25608908/stopping-in-built-php-server-on-mac-mavericks-livecode/76279055#76279055)

I have kinda this problem too, running on osx 10.13 with php mamp 8.1.x

First you need to check list port that php server running by this command on terminal:

```
ps -ef | grep php
```

then this will result

```
  501   714   637   0  3:21PM ??         1:35.58 php /Users/oreyon/.vscode/extensions/zobo.php-intellisense-1.1.3/vendor/felixfbecker/language-server/bin/php-language-server.php --tcp=127.0.0.1:49712 --memory-limit=4095M
  501  6428  6359   0  5:02PM ttys006    0:00.14 php spark serve
  501  6429  6428   0  5:02PM ttys006    0:00.05 /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php8.1.13/bin/php -S localhost:8080 -t /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/siabsensmkn3/public/ /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/siabsensmkn3/vendor/codeigniter4/framework/system/Commands/Server/rewrite.php
  501  6471  6431   0  5:02PM ttys007    0:00.00 grep php
```

The column number 2 is the PID port

You can type on terminal

```
kill 6428
```

this will remove process pid 6428 which is spark serve process

check again list PID with

```
ps -ef | grep php
```

if there is no php spark on the list, then you have succeeded

```
  501   714   637   0  3:21PM ??         1:35.58 php /Users/oreyon/.vscode/extensions/zobo.php-intellisense-1.1.3/vendor/felixfbecker/language-server/bin/php-language-server.php --tcp=127.0.0.1:49712 --memory-limit=4095M
  501  6532  6477   0  5:09PM ttys007    0:00.00 grep php
```

Don't forget to close terminal on php spark serve you running on, for me even if i kill the PID the list still will be there if we no close the terminal.

you can try running the spark serve with command:

```
php spark serve --port=8080
```

so you use only one port.

To prevent another port process the same serve, you can running spark serve on terminal.

So when you press **control + c** the spark serve will stop, no notification though, but you can make sure this will work or no `with ps -ef | grep php`

Hope this help